# WSO2: Installing Micro Integrator 8.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to install WSO2 Micro Integrator but the WSO2 website is not very helpful. The instructions on the website is for 7.x but all the downloads are 8.x. (I want to install 8).

The website talks about a Windows installer but the download is a .zip file without any installer. There also seems to be no micro integrator inside the zip file, only Integration Studio.

If you click on the "product page" link on the installation page (https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/installation/install_in_vm_installer/), you do go to the Enterprise Integrator page (https://wso2.com/integration/), but from there the download button takes you to the Integration Studio page (https://wso2.com/integration/integration-studio/).

Where is the download and installer for the latest Micro Integrator?

Does it mean I have to install Micro Integrator 7 but use Integration Studio 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Micro Integrator version 8, last version is 7. Or if you use it from WSO2 API Manager the version is 4.X.X. (yes this product versioning is a bit tricky)

On the other hand, there is a version 8 of Integration Studio. Which is a complete different product (an IDE). You can use it with whatever WSO2 Micro Integrator (or even WSO2 ESB ) version you wish.

So yes. You can use Micro Integrator 7 and work with Integration Studio 8.

Answer (score 0):

I found this little snippet on the WSO2 website. I have installed APIM 4.0.0 and got everything to run.

"Download API Manager 4.0.0 to get the latest version of Enterprise Integrator."